# How to specify a datetime object as a Central Standard Time or other timezones not UTC in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am developing a web application where User calls to customers and Customer may be in different country so I need to consider timezone also. So I have two input controls like "Next FollowUp DateTime" and "Next Followup Time Zone".

So user will ask to customers that what is the next follow up datetime and TimeZone. Let's say for example NextFollowUpDateTime is "21/3/2017 10:40PM" and the "Next Followup TimeZone" is CST(Central Standard Time)

So while saving to database I want to convert this to selected TimeZone, let's say CST. I am not able to specify the datetime object as CST.

Following I have tried:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(NextFollowupDatetime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dateTime,”Central Standard Time”);
```

Here I am able to specify datetime as UTC so it can be converted into another timezones. But I want to specify for other timezones also. Just my intention is to convert the selected datetime into selected timezone (CST or other) then convert it to UTC then save it to database.

Comment: Just don't use DateTime. Use DateTimeOffset and specify the offset explicitly. With `DateTime` the only timezone you can trust is `UTC`. `DateTimeKind.Local` means the system's timezone which can be *anything*.

Comment: can you give an example for DateTimeOffset, How to specify that object as CST time using DateTimeOffset

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: DateTimeOffset is far from the panacaea you're implying it is. The OP would still need to be able to get the right offset to start with. Using `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Unspecified` and converting from one `DateTime` value to another should work - but personally I'd say Noda Time is a better solution...

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't imply it's a panacea, that would be NodaTime. With DateTime though only UTC is reliable. In fact, any DST rule change can invalidate the offsets of future dates. I just couldn't write the entire standard response again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DateTime` itself only has three kinds:

- Unspecified (no specific time zone)
- UTC
- Local (system-local)

It doesn't have the notion of being in a *specific* non-UTC, non-local time zone.

If you want to convert from one time zone to another, you could call [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime, TimeZoneInfo, TimeZoneInfo)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass in a `DateTime` with an `Unspecified` kind.

However, I would personally - and I'm rather biased here - suggest using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library instead of using the BCL types.

That way you can create a `ZonedDateTime` which "knows" it's in the original time zone, and then use `ZonedDateTime.InZone` to create a new value which "knows" it's in the other time zone. Your code will be a lot clearer in terms of which values are in a specific zone vs which are "local" in a general sense (i.e. not anchored to *any* time zone) as they'd be `LocalDateTime` values.